# $\lVert f \rVert_p = \max\limits_{g \in L^q(E), \lVert g \rVert_{q} \leq 1} \int_E fg$ (question from Royden)

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Question (from Royden): For $1 \leq  p < \infty$, $q$ the conjugate of $p$, and $f \in L^p(E)$, show that $\lVert f \rVert_p = \max\limits_{g \in L^q(E), \lVert g \rVert_{q} \leq 1} \int_E fg$.

Answer:
From Holder, $$\int_E | fg| \leq \lVert f \rVert_p \lVert g \rVert_q.$$ So, $
\max\limits_{g \in L^q(E), \lVert g \rVert_{q} \leq 1} \int_E | fg| \leq \max\limits_{g \in L^q(E), \lVert g \rVert_{q} \leq 1}  \lVert f \rVert_p \lVert g \rVert_q =  \lVert f \rVert_p.$ In addition, we have that $g^* = \text{ sgn}(f) \frac{|f|^{p-1}}{\lVert f \rVert_p^{p-1}}$ is in $L^q(E)$, $\lVert g^*\rVert_{q} = 1$ and $\int_E f g^* = \rVert f \lVert_p.$ Thus, $\lVert f \rVert_p = \max\limits_{g \in L^q(E), \lVert g \rVert_{q} \leq 1} \int_E fg$.

Do you see any errors in this?

Comment: no it's correct

Comment: What is E? Right now its not clear why g^* is in L^q.

Comment: @wroobell E is any measurable set

Comment: Ok, its late night in here and i have mistaken absolut value with norm. Looks all right.

Comment: The only mistake I can spot is the missing umlaut in Hölder.

Comment: missing a case $||f||_p = 0$$

Comment: @runaround Yes, I forgot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the only concerns are:
 - Hölder, not Holder. 
 - The case where $f\equiv  0$ should be treated separately.